# SD card not working (XPS13)

Tags: realtek, sd-card, xps

I have a XPS13 (9350) edition with a built-in SD card reader. Running Xenial Ubuntu.  When I insert a SD card, nothing happens. The output of `lspci -nnk`:

```
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [1028:0704]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

The output of `blkid -o device`:

```
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
/dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p3
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1
/dev/nvme0n1
```

The output of `lshw -C generic` (just the device in question):

```
*-generic
       description: Unassigned class
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:276 memory:dc100000-dc100fff
```

I talked to someone else who also has Xenial running on their XPS13 and they mentioned that some capabilities are missing (i.e., they have `pm msi pciexpress` in addition to `bus_master cap_list`. They said that they have no problem with their SD card reader.

I'm a bit stumped as to what to do here. I found some threads that discuss issues with earlier Linux kernels (e.g., 4.3) that require compiling in some drivers. It's possible that something wasn't set up properly when I installed Xenial. I also had to upgrade the kernel to 4.6-997 (intel-drm-next branch) since there was a screen flicker bug on the 4.4 branch that ships with Xenial.

Does anyone have suggestions for what I should look at next. It's also possible the SD card reader is defective, but I'm not sure how to determine whether this is the case. Is there a simple way to test this?

Comment: Update: I do see the `pm msi pciexpress` in the capabilities list when running `lshw` with root privileges. However, I don't see `mmc*` devices under `/dev`. Is this a possible clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SD card reader was broken. Replaced under warranty and it works now.